# Getting Binary Input Through an audio Jack Port using QT

Tags: qt, audio, qml, jack

I want to get a binary(or analog) input through the port Jack for a Desktop Application.
Has anyone knows if it's possible in Qt? And How?
I found some libraries as "http://jackaudio.org/", but I con't know how to implement.

Any help will be very appreciated,

Thank you!